# Подтверждение email пользователя через API

Tags: php, laravel, api, oauth2, passport

Разрабатываю `API` для мобильных клиентов на `Laravel`. В качестве аутентификации пользователя использую `Laravel Passport` и выдаю им `Personal Access token` при логине в систему.

Не могу придумать, как реализовать систему подтверждения `email` (моб. телефона - не важно) при регистрации пользователя. Необходимо, чтобы подтверждение происходило с помощью `четырёхзначного числа` - кода.

Традиционно сайты высылают письмо с кодом активации **после** отправки регистрационной формы и только после этого активируют учетную запись. Насколько я понимаю, в этом случае запись о пользователе в БД уже будет существовать. Соответственно, пока пользователь не подтвердит ее, теоретически возможно, что за это время придёт другой человек и захочет создать учётку с таким же ящиком. И тут в базе возникает 2 неактивированных записи. Рано или поздно, один из пользователей активирует аккаунт, тогда что делать со вторым? Разумеется я понимаю, что код активации временный, но эту проблему он не решает.

Мне такой подход не очень нравится. Хотелось, чтобы запись о пользователе создавалась только после того, как он подтвердил пароль и зарегистрировался.
Как в таком случае устроить логику на сервере и общение с клиентом?

Я примерно надумал следующее:

1. Пользователь вводит свой email
2. Мобильный клиент отправляет в API пользовательский email
3. API создаёт запись в отдельной таблице, где есть соответствие email - код
4. API отравляет на почту пользователя письмо с кодом
5. Пользователь вводит код в поле подтверждения email и заполняет прочие поля формы регистрации
6. Мобильный клиент отправляет все пользовательские данные в API вместе с кодом
7. API в отдельной таблице (users) создаёт учётку пользователя

Насколько безопасен такой подход и какие есть минусы? Что посоветуете?

Answer (score 1):

> Пользователь вводит код в поле подтверждения email и заполняет прочие
>   поля формы регистрации

Так не работает, обычно вы сперва все заполняете, если успешно заполнили, то остается ввести только проверочный код, для активации. Поэтому вносить все-же придется :)

Вполне нормальная практика, создать табличку для неактивированных пользователей, например `users_not_activated` - там хранить все что пользователь ввел, чтобы перенести из этой таблички в `users`, ему нужно ввести правильный код.

Когда он вводит код - ищем по таблице `users_not_activated` по полям `email-code`, если нашли, то переносим в основную, и сразу-же выполняем еще один запрос на удаление всех записей в `users_not_activated` с текущим `email`. И все ;)

Если вы боитесь мусора, то я вас успокою, индексированный поиск и при нескольких миллионах будет работать быстро, поэтому проблем нет, все в пределах погрешности. Тем более что вы можете фиксировать время создания записи в эту временную таблицу, и раз в неделю подчищать старые (неактуальные) записи.

Comment: Меня не мусор пугает. Мне сам пайплайн кажется костыльным. Но спасибо за ответ!

Comment: @rugleb ваш вариант, кажется куда костыльнее) сперва отправить мыло, потом ввести код, потом заполнять поля. А если страница потеряется? В предложенном мной варианте, можно легко в письме указывать урл активации (т.е. чтобы не код вводить, а просто по ссылке перейти).